# How to find JSON value in Grails

Tags: grails

I wanted to find if value exists in `JSON`.

Here is my example JSON:

```
data : [{id:1, name:'John'}, {id:2, name:'Harry'}]
```

then I will use the value from `params` such as

```
params.id  // id=1
```

to find does it exist in `data.id` or not

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
def data = [{id: 1, name: 'John'}, {id:2, name: 'Harry'}]
Map value = data.find { it.id == params.id }

if (value) {
    // Value exists
    println("Value with id $params.id" + value)
} else {
   // Not exits
}
```

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find(groovy.lang.Closure)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Groovy Slurper to do this. Follow the blog by Mr Haki 
http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2014/08/groovy-goodness-relax-groovy-will-parse.html

```
import groovy.json.*
import static groovy.json.JsonParserType.LAX as RELAX
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def data = "[{'id':1, name:'John'}, {id:2, name:'Harry'}]"
def result =  jsonSlurper.setType(RELAX).parseText(data)
```

https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5153114243989504